# Typecast object in class based on type in SET

Tags: c#, json

I´m trying to do something like this

```
    public decimal Duration
    {
        get
        {
            return this.durationField;
        }
        set
        {
           this.meðallíftímiField = {if (typeof(value) == typeof(String)) return Convert.ToDecimal(value);}
        }
```

Because i´m getting this object from Json object on the client, and sometimes it will be a value of type string, and sometimes of type decimal.

Could someone help me?
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet value always be of type decimal, because property type is **decimal**.

You can use this function to set duration

```
public decimal Duration {get;set;}
public void SetDuration(object duration)
{
   if(duration is decimal)
      Duration = (decimal)duration;
   else if(duration is string)
   { 
      Duration = decimal.Parse((string)duration);
   }
}
```